# Revoking tasks calling subprocesses in Celery

Tags: python, subprocess, celery, celery-task

I have a celery task calling a bash command (I can use os.system() or subprocess.Popen()).

When I call :

```
revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

on my task, the subprocess executing my bash command and created by my task is not killed. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, a SIGTERM signal is sent when `terminate=True`.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks

Since SIGTERM can be ignored, maybe try sending a SIGKILL?

Comment: I tried already with SIGKILL, but it seems that the signal is not transferred to the subprocess

Comment: When you start your subprocess, are you using `shell=True`?

Comment: No, when I do so, things don't go well. Are you saying that a SIGKILL  signal should be transferred to subprocesses ?

Comment: No. If you were dealing with this on the command line you would end up using something like `pkill` to kill the process group. Obviously, we are dealing with the additional abstraction of celery (you want to to kill the group of processes associated with the TASK, not the entire celery process group). I'm guessing you might be able to attach to the "task revoked" signal: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-revoked and manually kill the child process (assuming you have stored the PID). I will try to mess around with a POC over the weekend for you.